# cannot install mysql-workbench-community on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-workbench

When I run

sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community

I get the error
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-workbench-community : Depends: libpython3.7 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I then ran

sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold

Which did not return anything

typing

python3 -v

Produces an error
if I type

python3 --version

I get
Python 3.8.5

If I try to run

sudo apt install libpython3.7

I get the error
E: Package 'libpython3.7' has no installation candidate

I cannot come up with a way to fix this I have recently updated from 19

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This was caused due to running an older version of MYSQL.
fix was to remove the mysql repository for tools and install the work bench via snap.

Comment: The snap version is too slow to start... as many other installed via snap

Answer (score 0):

Click [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-install-mysql-workbench-in-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145361/how-to-install-mysql-workbench-in-ubuntu)

> Read the comment section.

FIXED issue by: 1. download mysql-apt-config at dev.mysql.com downloads. 2. install using apt dpkg -1 mysql-apt-config_z.x.c_.deb 3.update 4. install workbench and mysql-server 5.start mysql service