# How to install Mysql-Workbench in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql-workbench

Problem installing Mysql-Workbench in Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
error cannot find repo...
```

tried:

```
sudo snap install mysql-workbench
error: cannot find service.mysql
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

Comment: FIXED issue by: 1. download mysql-apt-config at dev.mysql.com downloads. 2. install using apt dpkg -1 mysql-apt-config_z.x.c_.deb  3.update 4. install workbench and mysql-server 5.start mysql service 6.It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [MySQL Workbench download page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)...

Dowload a version and do:

```
sudo dpkg -i <your_download.deb>
```